# I have two functions in App Scripts for Google Sheets but the first function doesn't run

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have two App Script functions. The first script is a custom function for the spreadsheet and the second copies the sheet multiple time. When I added the second function to the project, the first function no longer works in the worksheet. In the cell, I get an error "unknown function 'getSheetName'" In the cell, it is "=getSheetName()"

If I remove the second function, the first one works fine. The second function duplicateSheet I have assigned as a macro whereas the first is an in cell function. The second function works when I run the macro.

This spreadsheet is a little league baseball team game schedule, batting order and whatnot. I use the sheet name as the name of the game in the schedule (game 1, 2 ...20). I want to look up the sheet name to be able to vlookup the day, time etc of the game that is on another sheet with the whole schedule.

I want to copy the sheet which is what the second script does because I make it better/easier to use and coping it manually every time to all the games have the same "updates" is a pain. These two scripts make this easier to do without having to do a lot of manual typing every time. I have this working in Excel but am trying to move to Google Sheets.
In a cell, when I input "=getSheetName()" it should return the name of the sheet e.g. "Game 1".

```
function getSheetName() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  return sheet.getName();
}

function duplicateSheetWithIncrementedName() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

  // Prompt user for the number of times to copy the sheet
  var numberOfCopies = Browser.inputBox('Number of Copies', 'Enter the number of times to copy the sheet:', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
  
  // Convert input to a number
  numberOfCopies = parseInt(numberOfCopies, 10);

  // Check if the input is a valid number
  if (!isNaN(numberOfCopies) && numberOfCopies > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfCopies; i++) {
      var newSheetName = 'G' + (i + 2);
      spreadsheet.duplicateActiveSheet().setName(newSheetName);
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('Invalid input. Please enter a valid number greater than 0.');
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand the situation of `When I added the second function the first one no longer works.`. Can I ask you about the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue?

Comment: My guess is that duplicateActiveSheet() is not allow by custom functions. - [Custom Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#advanced)

Comment: What do you get in the cell that contains `=getSheetName()`, blank, #ERROR?

Comment: FWIW,  `getSheetName` is the custom function. Though it doesn't appear in the list of functions, if "=getSheetName()" is entered in a cell, it _will_ return the name of the sheet BUT it is _NOT_ dynamic. `duplicateSheetWithIncrementedName()` is run from the editor and _does_ duplicate and rename a sheet. BUT the value of `getSheetName` is returned as "copy of Sheet1' and once the sheet is renamed, "getSheetName" does not update to the new sheet value. If "getSheetName" is used in a new cell on the duplicated sheet then it _does_ return the new sheet name.

Comment: @TheWizEd I get an error "unknown function 'getSheetName'  " In the cell, it is "=getSheetName()"

Answer (score 0):

The first function 'getSheetName' has an error when the sheets are copied in the duplicateSheetWithIncrementedName macro. That is because when google copies the sheet it first names the new sheet "Copy of G5"/ The getSheetName function can't handle that name and creates an error and the function isn't dynamic and doesn't rerun when the sheet is given is appropriate name. Once I go in and update the function and it reruns, it works as intended. I saw another similar question that suggested including a cell reference as an input to the function "=getSheetName(B17)". Then if you change cell B17, that causes the function to recalculate.